# applicationWillResignActive x screen saver

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Inside my applicationWillResignActive, I have to do certain functions that are just intended to run in the case the app is resigning because the iPhone is entering on screen saver mode.

Is there a way to know if this is the case inside applicationWillResignActive?

Any clues?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can distinguish the reason for the state change. You should run those tasks *every* time you have such a state change, however, as the OS can (and will) force your app to terminate while in an inactive or background state.

Comment: I was afraid this would have no solution. Thank.s